# Converting String into bit in iOS

Tags: objective-c, base64

```
var index=2;
var validFor="CAAA";
function isDependentValue(index, validFor)
{
   var base64 = new sforce.Base64Binary("");
   var decoded = base64.decode(validFor);
   var bits = decoded.charCodeAt(index>>3);

   return ((bits & (0x80 >> (index%8))) != 0);
}
```

The above code is written in Javascript.I have to do the same in my iOS app.How can i do it with Objective-c.I have decoded the validFor string by using of this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704915/how-to-decode-base64-encoded-png-using-objective-c)

Need help on this

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert a string to base64, the code below shows a brief example:

```
NSData *nsdata = [@"String to encode"
  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Get NSString from NSData object in Base64
NSString *base64Encoded = [nsdata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```