# Django rest framework : How to serve binary directly in the body

Tags: django, image, rest, download, django-rest-framework

I need to return an Image (binary) directly in the body request, but what i get in response is a file generated with no extension and an empty array/json inside!

I'm using python 3, Django==1.10.5 and djangorestframework==3.5.3, drf-extensions==0.3.1 (for the nested routes) and django-extra-fields==0.9 for the ImageField.

(I have tried without django-extra-fields, it's the same)

I have already found one solution (thx a lot Enix ;p) with the base64 here :[Django rest framework : How to download image with this image send directly in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874638/django-rest-framework-how-to-download-image-with-this-image-send-directly-in-t)

**But my boss doesn't want base64 and just want the binary inside the body response.**

#### My models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Image')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Images')

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(
        help_text=_('Creation date'),
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False
    )

    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(
        help_text=_('Last modification date'),
        auto_now=True
    )

    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
```

#### My serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image_file',)
```

#### My views.py

```
class ImageViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    http_method_names = ['get', 'put']
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        image = Image.objects.last()  # This is just for the exemple.
        filename = image.image_file
        size = filename.size
        response = FileResponse(open(filename.path, 'rb'), content_type="image/png")
        response['Content-Length'] = size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % 'notification-icon.png'

        return response
```

I have made some test with :

> django.core.files.File, filewrapper, deactivate the serializer

but have not yield desired results...

If someone find out what I'm doing wrong or maybe forgot something in the settings ? Any help regarding the same would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to return your image with django-rest-framework? It would be way easier to return it directly in a normal django view...

Comment: probably my mistake...

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found my mistake...

I was trying to override get_queryset... and not the get method which doesn't work too because I need to override the list method!

I need to sleep a little bit more ;p

Here is a solution that work's great for me with Streaming for download large file if needed :

#### My models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Image')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Images')

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(
        help_text=_('Creation date'),
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False
    )

    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(
        help_text=_('Last modification date'),
        auto_now=True
    )

    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
```

#### My serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image_file',)
```

#### My views.py

```
class ImageViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    http_method_names = ['get', 'put']
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    pagination_class = None

        def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            image = Image.objects.get(pk=get_your_good_record)
            filename = image.image_file
            size = filename.size

            content_type_file = mimetypes.guess_type(filename.path)[0]

            response = StreamingHttpResponse(open(image.image_file.path, 'rb'), content_type=content_type_file)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % str(filename)
            response['Content-Length'] = size

            return response
```

So easy ;p